# Is it possible to attach Power Armor to the station?

Tags: fallout-4

In the menu screen, Fallout 4 shows an image (see below) of Power Armor being attached to a Power Armor Station via hooks and chains. The best I've been able to do is exit my armor when near the station, but it never actually attaches.

Is this something in-game that actually happens, or does the station not have anything to do with storing Power Armor?

[image: screenshot of power armor attached to the power armor station on the main menu]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is just additional visual fidelity in pre-rendered scenes.

The power armor does not hook into the power armor station in game, however if you exit the power armor near the power armor station and then use the power armor station's 'craft' option it will move the armor into a similar position to the pre-rendered scenes, just without the chains:

[image: power armor]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't attach per se, but if you exit the armor close to the station and then activate the station, the armor will lock into place in the correct position.

You can see this happen in *Day[9]*'s playthrough [here](https://youtu.be/LxJ1cQcy-Jo?t=45m25s).

Answer (score 0):

If you have say, 2 stations side by side and 2 suits of armor, selecting crafting at the station will pull in the *closest* suit to that station; even if it is already docked at another station!  (Not sure what the range on that is though, the stations were side by side with a suit docked in on, the other was a couple of steps away)